Callable default on unique field will not generate unique values upon migrating
Using Django/DRF to create a CRUD api
I'm trying to use the RandomUUID to create a UUID from Postgres:
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.functions import RandomUUID

class Year(models.Model):
    year_id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True, default=RandomUUID, editable=False)

When I run python manage.py makemigrations
It gives me this error:
Callable default on unique field year.year_id will not generate unique values upon migrating

What am I doing wrong?
I want Django ORM to tell Postgres to create the UUID. I don't want to use Python's uuid module.

Did this model exist before you ran makemigrations ?  If so, it might be easier to backup your db, delete all your migration files up to the file that defines Year, then run makemigrations again.

Though that solution might not be possible depending on your infrastructure.

What version of Postgres?

@AdrianKlaver v15

@LordElrond yes it did. sounds like I just need to delete any previous migration files?

@LordElrond I just tested this and your right! I just had to delete the previous migrations and run makemigrations again. Feel free to post it as answer


If you're using PostgreSQL < 13, ensure you have the pgcrypto extension correctly installed. According to the docs:


On PostgreSQL < 13, the pgcrypto extension must be installed. You can use the CryptoExtension migration operation to install it.


Alternatively you can use Python's uuid4. In your models.py, import uuid4

from uuid import uuid4

Then in your models:
year_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4(), editable=False)


I clearly state that I don't want to use python's uuid and I've already seen the first part of your answer in the docs....
